# C# dataadapter delete command

Tags: c#

I'm making my own storage program using SQL in C#
my problem is everytime I delete an entry, all of the columns get deleted, how do I fix this? I use the program like this, is there any kind of query I should use if i just want to delete 1 row?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e6AZw.jpg)

Comment: You should add a where clause which has the delete logic on your delete statement

Comment: If you don't specify a `WHERE` clause, it will delete all rows. That is very basic SQL, perhaps you need to learn some SQL before coming here?

Answer (score 0):

Try doing something like,

```
          string delete=" delete from dbo.testtable where 
                      testtableid='123'";
            Using(SqlConnection con=new SqlConnection 
                  ('yourconnectionstring){
           using (SqlCommand scmd=new SqlCommand 
               (delete,con){
             con.open();
             cmd.executenonquery();
               }
               }
```

Answer (score -1):

Like David said, this is basic SQL.

However, if you're doing C# it's usually a pretty bad idea to be writing raw SQL anyways.  EntityFramework can take care of these details for you.